Prove $T$ is a contractive mapping

For two functions $x$ and $y$ in $C[0,1]$, define
$$d(x,y)=\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}|x(t)-y(t)|.$$Admit that
$(C[0,1],d)$ is complete.  Consider the following mapping
$$T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]: x\mapsto T(x),$$ where $$T(x):
 [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}: t\mapsto 1+\int\limits_{0}^{t}\cos (s)x(s)ds.$$
Show that $T$ is a contractive mapping. Deduce that there exists a
unique $x$  s.t $$(\forall t\in [0,1])\quad
x(t)=1+\int\limits_{0}^{t}\cos (s)x(s)ds.$$

My attempt:
$d(T(x),T(y))=\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}|T(x)(t)-T(y)(t)|=\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\left\vert\int\limits_{0}^{t}\cos (s)x(s)ds-\int\limits_{0}^{t}\cos (s)y(s)ds\right\vert=\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\left\vert\int\limits_{0}^{t}\cos (s)(x(s)-y(s))ds\right\vert\leq\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\int\limits_{0}^{t}|x(s)-y(s)|ds=\int\limits_{0}^{t_0}|x(s)-y(s)|ds$
$\leq \max\limits_{0\leq s\leq 1}|x(s)-y(s)|\int\limits_{0}^{t_0}ds=d(x,y).t_0$.
The problem is if $0\leq t_0<1$, then $T$ is a contractive mapping. But we can't deduce like that if $t_0=1$. How can I deal with this case? I would be much appreciated if someone can continue this path or have better ways to deal with the rest of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Using that cosine is positive on $[0,1]$, and continuing with your bound:
$$d(T(x),T(y))\leq\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\left\vert\int\limits_{0}^{t}\cos (s)(x(s)-y(s))ds\right\vert\leq\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\int\limits_{0}^{t}|\cos(s)|\cdot|x(s)-y(s)|ds\leq\\\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\int\limits_{0}^{t}|\cos(s)|d(x,y)ds=d(x,y)\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\int\limits_{0}^{t}|\cos(s)|ds=d(x,y)\max\limits_{0\leq t\leq 1}\int\limits_{0}^{t}\cos(s)ds= d(x,y)\sin(1), $$
with $\sin(1)<1$.

Very clever approach  :)

$T$ is an affine map, and its linear part is $L:x \mapsto (t\mapsto \int_{0}^{t} \cos (s) x(s) ds)$, so $dT = L$, one just need to compute the subordinate norm of $L$ if it is strictly less than $1$, $T$ will be contracting since $d$ comes from the uniform norm.
Let $x \in C([0,1])$,
$$\begin{align*}
\|L(x)\|_\infty &= \left\|t\mapsto \int_{0}^{t} \cos (s) x(s) ds \right\|_\infty \\
&\leqslant \|x\|_\infty \cdot \left\|t\mapsto \int_{0}^{t} \cos (s)  ds \right\|_\infty\\
&= \|x\|_\infty \cdot \left\|t\mapsto \sin(t) \right\|_\infty \\
&= \sin(1) \|x\|_\infty
\end{align*}$$
So since $\sin(1) < 1$, $T$ is contracting, therefore you have an unique fixed point that verifies the hypothesis.
